# Xamarin: how update webview (modules) without upgrading App

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

In company that I'm working we have a Native Android app that upgrade the Webviews without upgrading de .apk

How it works:

1 - we have js, css, html modules on app that can be updated separately. We have a folder for every module and its zipped and available on internet.

2 - When our costumer opens the app we checked if have some new features or fixes from each module, and if it is the app download the needed module, unzip it and this module is updated.

I'm asking it because we'll start a new app and we are thinking to use Xamarin, because we will have to deploy to IOS and ANDROID.

This feature cannot be negotiated because some of our clients have a bureaucratic way to upgrade the apps for his employees and this process takes at least 2-3 days. So we need to upgrade the .apk (for example) as little as possible.

So could I implement any solution, as I've implemented in Android, for it that will be available to both platforms?? Xamarin is the right choice??

Comment: However you are doing this via Java code, you can do via `Xamarin.Android`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So could I implement any solution, as I've implemented in Android, for it that will be available to both platforms?

There are two approaches to implement your feature on both platforms, they are `Xamarin.andorid+Xamarin.Ios` and `Xamarin.form`.

**Xamarin.android+Xamarin.Ios**

It is depends on .Net framework. You can use c# to develop android app, and It is similar with Java Android, many logic code of Java Android can be reused. If you did Java Android before you can learn `Xamarin.Android` easily. As the @SushiHangover said " you are doing this via Java code, you can do via Xamarin.Android". But you need to develop the Ios platform from the beginning using `Xamarin.Ios`.

**Xamarin.form(Cross Platform)**

It is also use C# language. You can write single code that can run on IOS, android , windows platform. But some specific feature need to achieve in specific platform. Your Java Android knowledge will not helpful for you. You will spend a lot of time to learn how to use `Xamarin.form`.

Xamarin.form guide: [Xamarin.Forms](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/)

> Xamarin is the right choice?

Obviously Xamarin can achieve webview updating, but for a Hybrid app `Cordova` is also a good choice. Using JavaScript to invoke android native function and IOS native function by the same Cordova plugin, it saves your time for learning Xamarin. It just depends on your choice.